# How to delete public storage files older than last one hour?

Tags: laravel, cron, laravel-7

I'm working on a project which requires deleting all files from `storage/public/dir_name/`. Example file name is `jIK4uh.png`. I am supposed to use a cron job for this task. Here is the method I'm following.

**app/console/commands/ClearPublicStorage.png**

```
class ClearPublicStorageCron extends Command {

  protected $signature = 'storage:clear';
  
  public function handle()
  {
      Log::info("Public storage files cleared!");

      // tasks logic here

      $this->info('Cron command run successfully');
  }
}
```

**app/Console/Kernel.php**

```
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel {
  protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('storage:clear')->hourly();
    }
}
```

Then running `php artisan schedule:run`

Now how to select all files that are older than last one hour and delete those in every hour by following this strategy? Or any other efficient idea to do this stuff ?

*Laravel version : 7.30*

Comment: Are you storing file name in database?

Comment: yeah. File info are storing in database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic idea is to using `storage lastModified` datetime

get last modified `datetime` from file

```
$fileTime=Storage::disk('public')->lastModified('dummy.pdf');

$fileModifiedDateTime=Carbon::parse($fileTime);

if(Carbon::now()->gt($fileModifiedDateTime->addHour())){

   //delete file here
}
```

If you are storing filename in database then you can delete based on file uploaded date

**Updated**

```
$files = Storage::disk("public")->allFiles("claim-images");
    
foreach ($files as $file) {
   $time = Storage::disk('public')->lastModified($file);
   $fileModifiedDateTime = Carbon::parse($time);
    
   if (Carbon::now()->gt($fileModifiedDateTime->addHour(1))) {
                
        Storage::disk("public")->delete($file);
    }
    
     //storage symbolic link files not required to delete.Still providing here for you reference
    
   if (File::exists(public_path('storage/' . $file))) {
        
         File::delete(public_path('storage/' . $file));
   }
}
```

Comment: `lastModified` throwing `File not found at path`  error.

Comment: where is your file located .can you comment exact path of file

Comment: the exact file path is `storage/claim-images/filename.png`. I am trying to get the last modified by`Storage::disk("public")->files("claim-images/filiname.png")`

Comment: then remove disk("public")-> from storage

Comment: $fileTime=Storage::lastModified('claim-images/filiname.png');

Comment: removing disk("public") causing error. because I'm using multiple storage disks

Comment: first try to access image so you can confirm it works or not since i am not sure how you configured file system.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233842/discussion-between-osman-rafi-and-john-lobo).

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

First I am getting all files from `temp-files` folder and put them in collection.

Looping through the collection and comparing each file last modified date and time to `now()->addHour()` and if it is older file will be deleted.

```php
public function deleteOldFiles() {
    $files = collect(Storage::allFiles('temp-files'));
    $files->each(function ($file) {
         $lastModified =  Storage::lastModified($file);
         $lastModified = Carbon::parse($lastModified);

         if (Carbon::now()->gt($lastModified->addHour())) {
             Storage::delete($file);
         }
     });

    return true;
}
```